# Force inserted new lines below the totals in Magento PDF invoice

Tags: magento-1.9, pdf

I have been able to insert new lines on my pdf invoice. It is working perfectly with positioning in right place.

However, when invoice content gets bigger but only **total part** goes to second page, my inserted new lines don't go to second page.

If products are moving to second page then only those new lines moves to second page after total.

I have tried with setting `$this->y -=10` (any number), but it keeps moving in first page.

**How do I force them to be below the total all the time? Any idea on this?**

**UPDATE 1**

Screenshots:
[image]

Comment: How are you making new lines now? `\r\n`?

Comment: `$page->drawLine(20, $this->y -=10, 570, $this->y, Zend_Pdf_page::SHAPE_DRAW_STROKE);` and `$page->drawText("Bank Detail: ", 30, $this->y -=20, 'UTF-8');`. These lines suppose to be under the **Total** all the time.

Comment: @AdarshKhatri, Hello I am facing same problem, please comment if you found any solution.

Comment: No, I haven't yet. Please add here if you find any.

Comment: @VinayaMaheshwari, please check http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/69715/force-inserted-new-lines-below-the-totals-in-magento-pdf-invoice/100717#100717 It worked for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, after digging into magento core functions, here is how I have achieved this:

**My `Namespace_ModuleName_Model_Sales_Order_Pdf_Invoice extends Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Pdf_Invoice` class**

```
public function getPdf($invoices = array())
{
  //.................
  //other stuff

 foreach ($invoices as $invoice) {
  //.................
  //other stuff

      /* Add totals */
        $this->insertTotals($page, $invoice);
        if ($invoice->getStoreId()) {
            Mage::app()->getLocale()->revert();
        }

     /* my new content
      * insert few lines, admin user etc
      */
      $page = end($pdf->pages); ///this is very important to force it go after total block ////
      $this->_insertPaidHistory($page, $invoice); //have separate custom function
  }
    $this->_afterGetPdf();
    return $pdf;
}
```

**Important**

Did you notice `$page = end($pdf->pages);` right before my new content! That's responsible to force my contenct always go after `total` block.

Hope this will help someone.

Answer (score 0):

So, I believe you are looking for something like this (because you need line breaks - notice \n):

```
$textChunk = wordwrap($value, 20, "\n");
foreach(explode("\n", $textChunk) as $textLine){
  if ($textLine!=='') {
    $page->drawText(strip_tags(ltrim($textLine)), 75, $line, 'UTF-8');
    $line -=14;
  }
}
```

I grabbed this code from [Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4950654/php-pdf-line-break#answer-4950852)

Comment: Thanks, it's not about inserting new line. My new lines are not sticking with total block. I have added screenshot, please see update.

Comment: Look at the `$line -=14;` value. You need to increment this each time to "move down the page"